# How to write a recursive string method that takes in int?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a recursive method called String song (int n).
Say I have a sentence: I have n candy, you take one out, pass it around, n-1 left.

I have n-1 candy, you take one out, pass it around, n-2 left.

and it goes on and stops when n = 0.

How do I put this string inside the song method? If I do: return "I have "+ n + " candy, you take one out...." 
It doesn't compile. How do I return both the int and the string together?

Thank you so much!

Comment: "It doesn't compile." Showing it would help then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I do: return "I have "+ n + " candy, you take one out...." It doesn't compile

It should compile. At least does for me.

```
public String song(int n) {
    return "I have "+ n + " candy, you take one out....";
}
```

But that isn't recursive at all; the function doesn't call itself.

> How do I put this string inside the song method?

What string? The candy name? Why not a parameter?

```
public String song(String candy, int n) {
    return "I have "+ n + " " + candy + ", you take one out....";
}
```

Should still compile.

> How do I return both the int and the string together?

If you've learned Java, you can't. Methods only have one return type. You could print the string, not return the whole song...

Really, though, you don't need to return the integer.

You need to call the function recursively, right?

So, you can do that like this

```
public String song(int n) {
    return "I have " + n + "candy.\n" + song(n-1);
}
```

But that will cause a StackOverflowError, so good luck coding the rest!

Comment: haters gonna hate.

Comment: not a hater - your answer enables misuse of the site. The OP didn't even provide code that has been asked for.

Comment: @MichaelMarkidis And some of us are nice enough to give a push in the right direction rather than spam post to the help center.

Comment: niceties are not always the best way to provoke learning. I'll remove my -1 however.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it! Thanks for all your help @cricket_007